# Parcelable implementation not working. App still makes network calls on device rotation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, parcelable

I have a fragment where I am making network calls to an API. My model implements **Parcelable** in order to save the state on device rotation. I have implemented the method but when the device is rotated, it still makes a network request. Somehow the Parcelable implementation isn't working.

Here's my code

**Movie.java (MODEL)**

```
package com.execube.genesis.model;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * Created by Prateek Phoenix on 4/24/2016.
 */
public class Movie implements Parcelable {

    private int mId;
    private String mOriginalTitle;
    private String mTitle;
    private  String mPosterPath;
    private  String mOverview;
    private  float mVoteAverage;


    private Movie(Parcel source) {

        mId=source.readInt();
        mOriginalTitle=source.readString();
        mTitle=source.readString();
        mPosterPath=source.readString();
        mOverview=source.readString();
        mVoteAverage=source.readFloat();
    }

    public Movie() {

    }



    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        mId = id;
    }

    public String getOriginalTitle() {
        return mOriginalTitle;
    }

    public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {
        mOriginalTitle = originalTitle;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return mPosterPath;
    }

    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
        mPosterPath = posterPath;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return mOverview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        mOverview = overview;
    }

    public float getVoteAverage() {
        return mVoteAverage;
    }

    public void setVoteAverage(float voteAverage) {
        mVoteAverage = voteAverage;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mId);
        dest.writeString(mOriginalTitle);
        dest.writeString(mTitle);
        dest.writeString(mPosterPath);
        dest.writeString(mOverview);
        dest.writeFloat(mVoteAverage);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR= new Parcelable.Creator<Movie>(){

        @Override
        public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Movie(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movie[0];
        }
    };


}
```

**PopularMoviesFragment.java**

```
package com.execube.genesis.views;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.execube.genesis.R;
import com.execube.genesis.model.Movie;
import com.execube.genesis.utils.API;
import com.execube.genesis.utils.OkHttpHandler;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.Response;

/**
 * Created by Prateek Phoenix on 4/24/2016.
 */
public class PopularMoviesFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "HELLO WORLD";
    private static final String POPULAR_MOVIES_ARRAY ="popular_movies" ;
    private ArrayList<Movie> mMovies;
    private RecyclerView popularMoviesList = null;
    private View progressBarPopular = null;

    public PopularMoviesFragment() {
    //empty constructor required
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            mMovies=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(POPULAR_MOVIES_ARRAY);
        }
        else {

            String url = API.BASE_URL+API.API_KEY+API.SORT_POPULARITY;
            OkHttpHandler handler= new OkHttpHandler(url, apiCallback);
            handler.fetchData();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putParcelableArrayList(POPULAR_MOVIES_ARRAY,mMovies);//Saving state of the ArrayList to avoid the network calls.
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popular_movies,container,false);
        popularMoviesList = (RecyclerView) content.findViewById(R.id.popular_recyclerView);
        progressBarPopular = content.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_popular);

        if(getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

            popularMoviesList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
        }
        else{
            popularMoviesList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
        }


        PopularMoviesAdapter mAdapter = new PopularMoviesAdapter();
        popularMoviesList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return content;
    }



    private Callback apiCallback =  new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            //TODO show error message from here but in UI thread
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                mMovies= parseItems(response.body().string());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v(TAG,"Exception caught: ",e);
            }
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBarPopular.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    popularMoviesList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //TODO add adapter
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private class PopularMoviesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private ImageView mPosterImage;

        public PopularMoviesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mPosterImage= (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.poster);
        }
    }

    private class PopularMoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PopularMoviesViewHolder>
    {


        @Override
        public PopularMoviesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.movie_item,parent,false);

            return new PopularMoviesViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PopularMoviesViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final Movie movie=mMovies.get(position);

            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(API.IMAGE_URL+API.IMAGE_SIZE_185+movie.getPosterPath())
                    .into(holder.mPosterImage);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mMovies.size();
        }
    }


    private ArrayList<Movie> parseItems( String jsonResponse) throws JSONException{

        JSONObject jsonData= new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        JSONArray moviesJSONArray= jsonData.getJSONArray("results");
        ArrayList<Movie> Movies= new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <moviesJSONArray.length() ; i++) {

            Movie movie= new Movie();
            JSONObject movieJson= moviesJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

            movie.setId(movieJson.getInt("id"));
            movie.setOriginalTitle(movieJson.getString("original_title"));
            movie.setTitle(movieJson.getString("title"));
            movie.setPosterPath(movieJson.getString("poster_path"));
            movie.setOverview(movieJson.getString("overview"));
            movie.setVoteAverage((float) movieJson.getDouble("vote_average"));


            Movies.add(movie);
        }

        return  Movies;
    }
}
```

**OkhttpHandler.java (networking code)**

```
package com.execube.genesis.utils;

import okhttp3.Cache;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;

/**
 * Created by Prateek Phoenix on 4/24/2016.
 */
public class OkHttpHandler {

    private String queryUrl;
    private static final String TAG = "CustomTAG1";
    private String mResponse;
    private Callback mCallback;

    public OkHttpHandler(String Url, Callback callback) {
        this.mCallback = callback;
        this.queryUrl = Url;
    }

    public void fetchData() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(queryUrl)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(mCallback);


    }

}
```

**ViewPagerFragment.java**

```
package com.execube.genesis.views;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.execube.genesis.R;

/**
 * Created by Prateek Phoenix on 4/24/2016.
 */
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewpager,container,false);

        ViewPager viewPager= (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        TabLayout tabLayout=(TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        final PopularMoviesFragment fragment1= new PopularMoviesFragment();
        final TopRatedMoviesFragment fragment2= new TopRatedMoviesFragment();

        viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return position==0?fragment1:fragment2;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 2;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return position==0?"POPULAR":"TOP RATED";
            }
        });

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return view;

    }
}
```

**MoviesActivity.java**

```
package com.execube.genesis.views;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.execube.genesis.R;

public class MoviesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies);

        View view= findViewById(R.id.viewpager_container);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment= fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.viewpager_container);

        if(fragment==null)
        {
            fragment= new ViewPagerFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.viewpager_container,fragment)
                    .commit();

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I would try moving the api call to onResume() and invoke it only if the data set is not there.

Comment: But I am performing that check in OnCreate() and as per my knowledge, OnCreate() is called on device rotation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you maybe made an error in your `Activity` like `add` or `replace` your fragment when re-creating your `activity` (when your device is rotated, your `activity` is recreated too).

About handling orientation changed, you can `setRetainInstance()` for your `Fragment`. [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html):

> If restarting your activity requires that you recover large sets of data, re-establish a network connection, or perform other intensive operations, then a full restart due to a configuration change might be a slow user experience. Also, it might not be possible for you to completely restore your activity state
>
> When the Android system shuts down your activity due to a configuration 
>   change, the fragments of your activity that you have marked to retain are not destroyed. You can add such fragments to your activity to preserve stateful objects.

```
// this method is only called once for this fragment
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // retain this fragment
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

// find the retained fragment on activity restarts
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    dataFragment = (DataFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(“data”);

    // create the fragment and data the first time
    if (dataFragment == null) {
        // add the fragment
        dataFragment = new DataFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, “data”).commit();
        // load the data from the web
        dataFragment.setData(loadMyData());
    }
```

> Caution: While you can store any object, you should never pass an object that is tied to the Activity, such as a Drawable, an Adapter, a View or any other object that's associated with a Context. If you do, it will leak all the views and resources of the original activity instance. (Leaking resources means that your application maintains a hold on them and they cannot be garbage-collected, so lots of memory can be lost.)

**Update**
I'm not sure, but in your case, you should `setRetainInstance()` for you `ViewPagerFragment` and:

```
    // make those fragments global variable.
    PopularMoviesFragment fragment1= new PopularMoviesFragment();
    TopRatedMoviesFragment fragment2= new TopRatedMoviesFragment();
```

Comment: I have added the MainActivity (here MoviesActivity) and the ViewPagerFragment code in the question, could you please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your activity, replace the following code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment= fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.viewpager_container);

if(fragment==null)
{
    fragment= new ViewPagerFragment();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.viewpager_container,fragment)
            .commit();

}
```

with the following instead:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
  fragment= new ViewPagerFragment();
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.viewpager_container,fragment)
     .commit();
}
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `onSaveInstanceState` in your main Activity with `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)`.